# Fiddler Change parameter post request and postdata OnBeforeRequest

Tags: fiddler

i want to change the name of parameter before the request here is special function but nothing works

```
static function ReplaceQueryParameter(sName: String, sValue: String)
{
    var re:RegExp;
    if (sValue == null) {
        re = new RegExp( "(" + sName + "=)(([^&]*)|$)");
     var   ret = gs_QueryString.replace(re, '');
        gs_QueryString = ret;
    }
    else {
        re = new RegExp( "(" + sName + "=)(([^&]*)|$)");
       var ret = gs_QueryString.replace(re, "$1" + sValue);
        gs_QueryString = ret;
    }
}


  static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session)
{


    gs_QueryString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oSession.requestBodyBytes);
    ReplaceQueryParameter('username','username1');
          SetBodyFromQueryString(oSession);

}
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with this code. For one thing, it looks like you're trying to share a single variable ("gs_QueryString") across multiple requests. That is going to result in race conditions and corruptions as multiple Sessions execute in parallel.

You're also getting confused about the data in the request.

The `requestBodyBytes` byte[] contains the bytes in the body of any POST or PUT. A GET doesn't have any body bytes.

The `url` string contains the URL including any QueryString parameters. All requests have a url.

If you're trying to change the QueryString, which is a part of the URL, use:

```
var gs_QueryString = oSession.url;
oSession.url = ReplaceQueryParameter('username','username1');
```

...and update the ReplaceQueryParameter function to return a value instead of trying to update an unprotected shared variable.